# Leaflet: z-index for canvas

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to control the **order** of *canvas*-elements in Leaflet?

If the layers are represented by *canvas* html-elements, then *canvas* that will turn out to be in the very top (with max *z-index*) will block any other *canvas* underneath. In this case, the order of those layers won't even matter, since eventually all *canvas* elements are blocked by the very top *canvas* element that covers the whole map.

If we set **preferCanvas** option to **false** in Leaflet, then every feature will be represented by html element(svgs/paths/etc), so we will have thousands of svg's elements in html structure. This way, the ordering (z-index) will start working, but it kills performance since *canvas* elements are not used anymore, and we have thousands of html-elements instead.

Are there any other options not to use *canvas* that blocks all layers underneath and at the same time not to create thousands of elements in html? Or maybe any option to use *canvas* but somehow overcome that issue and make ordering work?

---

Here it is how we set up z-index for the pane: ("order" value comes from a prop of the component):

```
useMapEffect(
  ({ instance }) => {
    if (order) {
      // A constant so as to not interfere with other built in layers
      const featureLayerStartZIndex = 350;
      const pane = instance.createPane(
        featureLayerContext.featureLayerPaneName
      );
      if (pane) {
        pane.style.zIndex = `${featureLayerStartZIndex + order}`;
      }
    }
  },
  [order]
);
```

Here you can see how it eventually looks like in the html structure:
[image: html structure]

Eventually, the only layer that is on the very top will be the interactive one, it will cover the map completely. Other canvas layers won't get any events as if they are static layers.

Comment: See concept of map panes in Leaflet: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-pane. Each layer type has it's own map pane, and these can be controlled by their zIndex value. When vector layer is rendered with `L.canvas` renderer, it's still by default rendered on overlay pane, but you can create separate map pane with it's own zIndex and render layer there.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I set z-index for a div element that has a "leaflet-pane" class, and I have "canvas" element as a child of that "leaflet-pane" element. So yeah, I actually set z-index to a "leaflet-pane". But the problem is that the very top "leaflet-pane" with nested "canvas" element will block any other "leaflet-pane" elements with their own canvas.

Comment: As far as "blocking" goes, there is no difference between SVG rendered layer or canvas rendered ones. Please post an example of code where with undesired behavior of canvas layers as far as "blocking" is concerned.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand where the problem is regarding canvas rendered layers. It would help if you would post reproducible example.